# NGINX override default TRACE behaviour

Tags: nginx, trace

Attempting to return a '501 Not Implemented' HTTP response while using NGINX as a proxy.  The default behaviour is to respond with '405 Method Not Allowed'.  Is anyone aware of how to circumvent the default 405 response?

We've attempted the following configuration options to no avail

```
  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS|CONNECT|TRACE)) {
     return 501;
  }

  error_page    405 =501 @405;
  location @405 {
     root                    /;
     proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000;
  }

  location / {
     proxy_pass            http://localhost:3000;
  }
```

**Environment**

nginx version: nginx/1.2.1

Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Set `proxy_intercept_errors on;` in proxy location blocks.

Comment: Xavier Lucas,  Thanks for the input, however this has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: @Corvusoft Can you clarify if you are trying to override an error code returned by the proxy or by nginx himself (on a static ressource for instance) ?